# creating a custom image based layout on android

Tags: android, image, layout

Is it possible to create a layout based on (background) images? For example, there is well know app called Appie that uses this picture as a homescreen:

[image]

I might be able to recreate the layout with a `TableLayout`, but this will be difficult to get it perfectly aligned with the buttons in the image. The default layout options make it very difficult, or maybe impossible, to allow for selection of the buttons on the image (especially when the buttons are in an arc-path).

Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues positioning a badge on the corner of a view. You can check my solved question:

- [Positioning a badge bubble on the left upper side of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541741/positioning-a-badge-bubble-on-the-left-upper-side-of-a-button)

About how it can be done. I would do it with a `RelativeLayout` and `TableLayout` as you mentioned, but to be completely sure, you can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to see how the xml are done but it might be ilegal to do it.