# Positioning a badge bubble on the left upper side of a button using Java

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am new to Android development and am following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541741/positioning-a-badge-bubble-on-the-left-upper-side-of-a-button/3542010#3542010), which adds a badge bubble on the top-left side of a button by setting its xml file.  Since I would like to dynamically create such UI instead of statically creation, can I know how to create equivalent UI using java code?

Comment: xml layout can be "dynamic" (see for example listview items layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to dynamically set FrameLayout.LayoutParams on your dynamically created ImageView (assuming you are going for the approach of a FrameLayout containing the button and bubble).

Some example code, written in notepad like a pro:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
// initialize button - text, background, etc
layout.addView(button, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ImageView badgeBubble = new ImageView(this);
// initialize badge - source image/drawable, scale type, etc
layout.addView(badgeBubble, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT));
```

This assumes your FrameLayout has been initialized and is called `layout`.